# Parse character string to list in R

Tags: r, parsing

I would like to parse a character string like

```
s <- "I(log(x1)+myfunc(x2,1:3))"
```

to a list like

```
list(I = list( log = "x1",
               "+",
               myfunc = list("x2", "1:3")
              )
    )
```

i.e.,

```
$I
$I$log
[1] "x1"

$I[[2]]
[1] "+"

$I$myfunc
$I$myfunc[[1]]
[1] "x2"

$I$myfunc[[2]]
[1] "1:3"
```

How could I write a function for this conversion? Any resources would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

On a second thought, I sometimes have something like `"I(log(x1)+log(x2))"`, in which case `"log"` can't be a name for two. When it does not happen, perhaps a starting point is [strsplit keeping the delimiters.](https://www.r-bloggers.com/strsplit-but-keeping-the-delimiter/)

```
tokens <- strsplit(x,'(?=[\\(\\),\\+\\-\\*/(\\s+)])', perl = TRUE)
```